# Problems Using NET Framework to access Windows Registry

Tags: security, winapi, permissions, registry, vb.net-2010

i'm using vb.net 2010, .net framework 3.5 and the procedure and the exception I get, are as follows:

[image]

I've been reading about manifest, and this and that, but what it seems to me is that i'm still missing something, will anybody kindly give me any suggestions?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to be elevated to modify this key. Run your process as admin.

Comment: thanks a lot. Well, how am I supposed to do that? Use a manifest? 
Should I go into the registry and change the key access permission?
Is it only possible when running under admin account? 
I apologize for my ignorance, but what's the short path for "run as admin"?  If i simply change the exe property to run as admin, should it make the trick?

Comment: Can't advise on best course of action without knowing your program's broader goals and usage

Comment: thanks. 
Well. I need to use the registry to create the keys for an external protocol, i have to redirect a link to my desktop app, like those outlook links. 
I have a web app that in a given time, the user will click a link and call the application with the selected record as parameter, and then it all takes place in my desktop app.
I could even just call the registry exported file, via Process.Start, but whenever i try to edit the application path, file is not recognized anymore as a registry's. So, I'm going other way, as long as it keeps me from doing manually

Comment: You don't want your app to run elevated all the time. You need a new process to perform the changes. Either re-start main exe with runas verb and args. Or a separate exe with manifest to run as admin.

Comment: Screenshots of code and exception dialogs escape text searches. If you want your question to be useful to others, make it discoverable by pasting code and the exception as **plain text**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be elevated to modify this key. The process that performs these registry modifications needs to run as admin.

Use the `requireAdministrator` option in the manifest. Or start the process using the `runas` verb.

Comment: thanks a lot. I will try that. I assume that I`ll fail a couple of times, so before I might ask new questions, would You kindly provide a couple of links of instructions, please?

Comment: Start by reading about UAC and related topics on MSDN. You need a very clear understanding of that before you proceed.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of! I usually enjoy doing such things, but for this case, i'd really love a recipe! Thanks, anyway.

Comment: A recipe is the last thing you need. Without understanding you'll get it wrong. No shortcuts here.

Comment: LOL I know. That's the life we choosed, right?! But sometimes... 
Well, thanks again, fellow.

Comment: So, i created the manifest, used the required permissions and it just worked.  Thanks, everybody. 
But, still I have a problem,that I can't create subkeys. Maybe it's something wrong I'm doing, will check for that later, but so far, so good, I can handle.

One thing that's tricking me is that when I try to read from HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Classes
I'm getting HKLM\Software\Classes instead.
Might make sense because my exe is compiled for x86, but anyway, that's a doubtful topic to me.

Comment: x86 process is subject to registry redirection. That's a different topic. I think I answered the question you asked.

Comment: Thanks. Will You kindly give me a few keywords or links about this registry redirection?

Comment: Websearch for msdn registry redirector